# ERC721-OpenZeppelin: This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created

Tags: contract-deployment, erc-721, truffle-deployment, nft

I know there are already a lot of topics that deal with the problem but their solutions didn't work for me.

this is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;


import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Mintable.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721Full, ERC721Mintable {


  struct Structure{
      string name;
      uint id;
  }
  Structure[] public listOfStructure;
  address public owner;
  constructor() public{
      owner = msg.sender;
  }


  function create(string memory _name) public{
      uint id = listOfStructure.length;
      listOfStructure.push(Structure(_name, id));
      mint(owner, id);
  }

}
```

Remix says `"This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created."`, I just started using nft so I know it could be a concept error, for example I didn't understand the concept of interface very well, but I don't think it's the same problem (maybe).

I tried to deploy with truffle but I have a similar error.

Thanks and sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: You must implement all the not implemented functions of `ERC721Full` and all the not implemented functions of `ERC721Mintable`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved using [0xcert](https://github.com/0xcert/framework) instead of openzeppelin.

Comment: Thank you, would you please post the code too